# Move constructor called more times than expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, move-semantics, data-race

I have stepped through this code but can't understand why move constructor is called 4 times instead of one. Shouldn't it be called only once? I have stepped through the code using CLion on Mac. Here is the outcome on the console:

```
Vehicle #0 Default constructor called

Vehicle #1 Initializing constructor called

Vehicle #0 move constructor called

Vehicle #0 move constructor called

Vehicle #0 move constructor called

Vehicle #0 move constructor called

Process finished with exit code 11
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <memory>

class Vehicle
{
public:
    //default constructor
    Vehicle() : _id(0), _name(new std::string("Default Name"))
{
    std::cout << "Vehicle #" << _id << " Default constructor called" << std::endl;
}

//initializing constructor
Vehicle(int id, std::string name) : _id(id), _name(new std::string(name))
{
    std::cout << "Vehicle #" << _id << " Initializing constructor called" << std::endl;
}

// move constructor with unique pointer
Vehicle(Vehicle && src) : _name(std::move(src._name))
{
    // move id to this and reset id in source
    _id = src.getID();
    src.setID(0);

    std::cout << "Vehicle #" << _id << " move constructor called" << std::endl;
};

// setter and getter
void setID(int id) { _id = id; }
int getID() { return _id; }
void setName(std::string name) { *_name = name; }
std::string getName() { return *_name; }

private:
   int _id;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> _name;
};


int main()
{
    // create instances of class Vehicle
    Vehicle v0;    // default constructor
    Vehicle v1(1, "Vehicle 1"); // initializing constructor

    // launch a thread that modifies the Vehicle name
    std::future<void> ftr = std::async([](Vehicle v) {
        v.setName("Vehicle 2");
    },std::move(v0)); // move constructor only called here?

    ftr.wait();
    std::cout << v0.getName() << std::endl; // this will now cause an exception

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site for *specific questions* about actual code.  You need to debug your own code.  Questions of the form "This code doesn't work" are not on-topic on Stack Overflow and are likely to be downvoted.  See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more information.

Comment: Pop a breakpoint in the move constructor and see what circumstances call it.

Comment: You create an extra thread and run a function with it. Do you know how many moves are performed in a thread creation when you pass a parameter? Apparently its 4 for async function on your system. What did you expect?